# How to remove settings.MEDIA_ROOT from file path

Tags: django, python-3.x

I have code which creates a thumbnail for videos as they are uploaded - it looks like this:

**views.py post method:**

```
if form.instance.thumbnail == 'images/clearpath_logo/Logo.jpg':
    thumb_title = form.instance.title.replace(" ", "")
    in_path = str(settings.MEDIA_ROOT) + "/" + str(form.instance.video_file)
    out_path = str(settings.MEDIA_ROOT) + "/images/" + thumb_title + ".png"
    if create_thumbnail(in_path, out_path):
        form.instance.thumbnail = "images/" + thumb_title + ".png"
```

where `create_thumbnail` is the helper function.. it looks as such:

```
def create_thumbnail(input_path, output_path):
    """
    Save first frame of video for use as video thumbnail.

    :param input_path: video input path
    :param output_path: image output path
    :return: Boolean
    """
    cap = cv2.VideoCapture(input_path)
    ret, frame = cap.read()
    if ret:
        return cv2.imwrite(output_path, frame)
    else:
        pass
```

My main concern here is removing `settings.MEDIA_ROOT` from each of the file paths. How can I avoid manually typing out the file paths as such? Or is there a way I can make a form method out of the helper function and call the form instance url directly? I want to clean up this code.

Comment: Why not change `create_thumbnail` to only take the `video_file`, then handle all the logic in `create_thumbnail` which then returns the output path.

Comment: The OpenCV `VideoCapture` method takes a URL.

Comment: I've tried to use the `form.instance.video_file.url` but this doesnt give the MEDIA_ROOT

Comment: I'm saying pass in `form.instance.video_file`. And prefix with `settings.MEDIA_ROOT` inside the function.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the information you've given and bearing in mind I know nothing about any of the forms, and I don't know what `cv2` does, here's how I might tidy this:

```
def create_thumbnail(video_file, title):
    """
    Save first frame of video for use as video thumbnail.

    :param video_file: video file from the form instance
    :param title: the title of the thumbnail
    :return: path to the thumbnail
    """
    in_path - f'{settings.MEDIA_ROOT}/{video_file}'
    out_path = f'{settings.MEDIA_ROOT}/images/{title}.png'

    cap = cv2.VideoCapture(input_path)
    ret, frame = cap.read()
    if ret:
        image = cv2.imwrite(output_path, frame)
        if image:
            return out_path
    return ''


if form.instance.thumbnail == 'images/clearpath_logo/Logo.jpg':
    thumb_title = form.instance.title.replace(" ", "")
    form.instance.thumbnail = create_thumbnail(form.instance.video_file, thumb_title)
```

*N.B. Note that your code does not deal at all well with someone naming a video file the same as someone else. The thumbnail will just be overwritten. One simple solution is to give the thumbnail a random name.*

Comment: The duplicate file name I am aware of (and is next on the list). Thanks for taking the time to write such detailed response. I was hoping there was a way to not have to manually write `settings.MEDIA_ROOT` anywhere. While your code looks a little better I am still not exactly happy with where I wish I could be with it.

Comment: What is `settings.MEDIA_ROOT` and `form.instance.video_file`?